# Calculation of a limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{ni}{\pi}-\frac{ni}{\pi}e^{i\pi/n}\right]^n $

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to find a limit, annndd I'm kind of stumped.  Mathematica is telling me the answer is $i$.  Having trouble seeing where this comes from.  Here is the limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{ni}{\pi}-\frac{ni}{\pi}e^{i\pi/n}\right]^n  $$

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Taylor series of $e^x$:
$$ \frac{ni}{\pi}(1-e^{i\pi/n}) = \frac{ni}{\pi}\left(-\frac{i\pi}{n} - \frac{i^2\pi^2}{2n^2} + O(n^{-3})\right) = 1 + \frac{i\pi}{2n} + O(n^{-2}) .$$
Now use $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x/n + O(n^{-2}))^n = e^x $.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I see how your work yields the correct answer, but I don't see how that limit yields $e^x$. It seems like all the terms except the $1$ will go to zero? How am I thinking wrong here?

Comment: It is a well known identity.  One way is to take logs to get $\frac{\ln(1+x/n)}{1/n}$ and then apply l'Hopital.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense. Thank you for your help!